# Why Kafka Consumer API isn't fetching data from multiple partitions of a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Note: Using kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1

I have created a kafka topic named: `consumer-tutorials` with `3 Partitions` as below:

```
C:\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1>.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --describe --topic consumer-tutorial
--zookeeper localhost:2181
Topic:consumer-tutorial PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: consumer-tutorial        Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: consumer-tutorial        Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: consumer-tutorial        Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

Once the topic created, I produced some data in each partition using Producer API as per below:

```
KafkaProducer<String,String> prod = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props); 

for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int x=start; x<end; x++)
    {
        prod.send(new ProducerRecord<String,String>("consumer-tutorial",i,Integer.toString(x),Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt(100))));     }
    start=end;
    end = start + 10;
}
prod.close();
```

Now when I am trying to fetch records / consume messages from this topic `consumer-tutorial` using following `Consumer API`:

```
KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("consumer-tutorial"));

while(true)
{
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

    for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records)
    {
        System.out.printf("Key: %s, Value = %s", record.key(), record.value());
    }

}
```

I am not getting any records while running this code. I checked `record` variable but there is no `KEY:VALUE` pair coming from `Poll`

[Watch on "records" shows nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfaPt.png)

Can anyone help me as why I am not getting any data to display.

```
NOTE: It works well when I have single partition topic.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe topic, internally lots of operation will happen like these 1. Find the group coordinator 2. send the group request and fetch the group leader 3. Leader will ensure any one joining to the group or leaving the group members 4. The leader willassign the partition to members based on the assignment strategy like(Range/RoundRobin). 5. Then each consumer member fetch the metadat from group coordinator.

Then It will fetches the records.  So first few iterations you wont get any data when you poll.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it will take first few iterations to fetch the records however in my case loop goes to infinite and `'Poll'` keeps polling endlessly. What I found later today that when I reset the group name with some new name (I used UUID to randomize the group name) then it keeps fetching data from topic using different partitions. So this concluded that the offset needs to be reset to the beginning so that consumer can start fetching data from the beginning and keeping group id everytime new keeps the offset pointer in the beginning. Now I want to know what's the way to set the offset to the beginning of the topic (not partition).. I tried using `'props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");`' and `seek` and `seekToBeginning` but all of them wouldn't work unless consumer has lost the offset track.. so is there any way guys through which I can set the offset pointer to the beginning ?